# Why air-datepicker does not support formatted datetime from database?

Tags: laravel, datepicker

In laravel 8.83 / air-datepicker 2.2.3 / jquery 3.6.0 app I need to use datepicker with time selection and in resources/js/app.js  I have :

```
require('air-datepicker/src/js/air-datepicker');
$('.datetime_picker').datepicker({
    toggleSelected: false,
    timepicker: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:m',
    buttons: ['today', 'clear'],
})
```

and in blade php file :

```
<span class="d-block mb-1">{{ $news->published_at }}</span>
        <input
            class="form-control datetime_picker"
            name="published_at"
            id="datetime_picker_published_at"
            value="{{ old('published_at', $news->published_at?->format('d.m.Y H:i')) }}"
            data-language="{{ app()->getLocale() }}"
            data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy H:i"
            data-clear-button="true"
            data-auto-close="true"
            autocomplete="off"
        />
```

As result when form is opened with existing date I see valid datetime in input, but
a) opening datetime pickup it has not existing date , but current date and time.
b) I can select date and hour by dragging hour scroller, but minutes are not selected when I drag minutes scroller
c) Can I add some “Select” button when I need to select datetime into input and close pickup dialog?